# How to run javascripts defined in a string full of html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to render a web page with in a web page. Page, I want to render is a regular web page containing javascript and html. I want to run the scripts in the page and the output in to a variable.

For example, if the page consists of:

`<html><body><script src="foo.js"></script></body></html>`

I want to read it in to a variable with

`var bar = $.get('page.html');`

And foo.js consists of

`for(var i=0;i<3;i++) document.write(i+'<br>');`

I want the following be in the variable:

`<html><body>0<br>1<br>2<br></body></html>`

Is this even possible?

Comment: If it contains HTML, it's not named 'page.js'. This being said, I don't really have an idea :)

Answer (score 2):

If you simply want the inner page to handle its rendering logic itself, better use an iframe.

Or you can try the jquery loadScript method. This will load the script in global context and also provides a success handler that can be utilized to construct your variable.

e.g.

```
$.getScript( "ajax/test.js", function( data, textStatus, jqxhr ) {
  console.log( data ); // Data returned
  console.log( textStatus ); // Success
  console.log( jqxhr.status ); // 200
  console.log( "Load was performed." );
});
```

For Further [help](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/)

Comment: I know I can get the contents of an iframe in to a variable, but it seems like such a silly way to do this. =(

Comment: try jquery.load, that can load the whole content into a desired html element
e.g. 
`$( "#element" ).load( "test.html" );` will load the content into the element with id "element"

[Info](https://api.jquery.com/load/)

Comment: The $.getScript looks like it might do the trick, except for this being an angular app and the page being an anchor in the same page. getScript doesn't do a full load for links such as these.

The page I am currently on is `http://localhost/app#!/foo/bar` and the page I want to get and run is `http://localhost/app#!/foo/bar/baz/123`

Comment: jquery.load does not parse javascript, the result is same as with jquery.get